# reactjs antd-mask-input field value disappears

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm new to react.js
I have a update form for users.
it has one antd-mask-input and two input (antd)
there is no problem for first load

[image: user info update form]
But if I click the avatar picture -> select a new one and then upload it; value in the phone number area is disappears
If I open another tab for different site and return back after 2 minutes it disappears again.

What should I do?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useAxiosPrivate from "../hooks/useAxiosPrivate";
import { Alert, Form, Button, Input, notification, Space, Upload } from "antd";
import { MaskedInput } from "antd-mask-input";
import { LoadingOutlined, PlusOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

function Soru() {
    let { id } = useParams();
    const [form] = Form.useForm();
    const axiosPrivate = useAxiosPrivate();
    const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);
    const [errMessage, setErrMessage] = useState(null);
    const [oneTime, setOneTime] = useState(true);
    const [api, contextHolder] = notification.useNotification();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState();
    const handleChange = (info) => { setLoading(info.file.status === "uploading"); };
    const customUpload = async ({ onError, onSuccess, file }) => {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("avatar", file);
        const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } };
        axiosPrivate
            .post(`http://localhost:3001/updateuser/${id}`, formData, config)
            .then((res) => {
                onSuccess(true);
                setLoading(false);
                setIsPending(false);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                onError({ event: err });
            });
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        if (oneTime) {
            console.log("only one time");
            axiosPrivate
                .get(`http://localhost:3001/users/byId/${id}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.statusText !== "OK") {
                        const error = response.data.message;
                        setErrMessage("response : " + error.name);
                        setIsPending(false);
                        return Promise.reject(error);
                    } else {
                        setIsPending(false);
                        form.setFieldsValue({
                            phoneNumber: response.data.phoneNumber,
                            firstName: response.data.firstName,
                            lastName: response.data.lastName,
                        });
                        setImageUrl(`http://localhost:3001/avatars/avatar_${id}.jpg`);
                        setOneTime(false);
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setIsPending(false);
                    console.log("err resp : " + err);
                });
        }
    }, []);

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        setIsPending(true);
        axiosPrivate
            .put(`http://localhost:3001/users/byId/${id}`, e)
            .then((response) => {
                setIsPending(false);
                api["success"]({ message: "saved", placement: "bottomRight" });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setIsPending(false);
                api["error"]({ description: err, placement: "bottomRight" });
            });
    };

    return (
        <Form
            form={form}
            autoComplete="off"
            labelCol={{ span: 10 }}
            wrapperCol={{ span: 8 }}
            onFinish={(values) => { onSubmit(values); }}
            onFinishFailed={(error) => { console.log("onFinishFailed : " + { error }); }}
        >
            {contextHolder}
            <Space direction="horizontal" style={{ width: "100%", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Upload
                    name="avatar"
                    listType="picture-circle"
                    className="avatar-uploader"
                    showUploadList={false}
                    customRequest={customUpload}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                >
                    {imageUrl ? (
                        <img
                            src={imageUrl}
                            alt="avatar"
                            style={{ width: "100%", borderRadius: "50%"}} />
                    ) : (
                        <button style={{ border: 1, background: "none" }} type="button">
                            {loading ? <LoadingOutlined style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} /> : <PlusOutlined style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} />}
                            <div style={{ marginTop: 8, marginBottom: -20, cursor: "pointer" }}>Upload</div>
                        </button>
                    )}
                </Upload>
            </Space>

            <Form.Item name="phoneNumber" label="phoneNumber">
                <MaskedInput mask="(000) 000 00 00" placeholder="phoneNumber" />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item name="firstName" label="firstName" rules={[{ required: true }, { whitespace: true }]}>
                <Input
                    placeholder="firstName"
                    maxLength={20}
                    onInput={(e) => {
                        e.target.value = e.target.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.target.value.slice(1);
                    }}
                />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item name="lastName" label="lastName" rules={[{ required: true }, { whitespace: true }]}>
                <Input placeholder="lastName" onInput={(e) => (e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase())} maxLength={20} />
            </Form.Item>
            <Space direction="horizontal" style={{ width: "100%", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ span: 24 }}>
                    <Button block type="primary" htmlType="submit" loading={isPending} danger={errMessage}>
                        Save
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
            </Space>
            {errMessage && (
                <Space direction="horizontal" style={{ width: "100%", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                    <Alert type="error" message={errMessage} />
                </Space>
            )}
        </Form>
    );
}
export default Soru;
```